# Is it "50 minutes of international calls" or "50 minutes of international calling"?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if it is *50 minutes of international calls* or *50 minutes of international calling*? For example:

> The plan comes with a lot of mobile data and 50 minutes of international **calls**/**calling**.

Do both sound natural and correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are correct but they have slightly different meaning.

'calls' means that your (possibly plural) call will continue to work until your minutes are all used up.

'calling' means you can continue to initiate new calls until your minutes are all used up.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I did not know that call(s) and calling had different meanings in the context of cellphone minutes.  Is there a link that provides more information on this difference?